# What are the total number of hats/outfits that Mario can get in Super Mario Odyssey?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

As the title says, I just want to know the total number achievable, and don't care about the names. Also, are there any outfits you can only get with amiibo?

Comment: There's plenty of guides out there that lists everything and how you obtain them... if you don't want that list... couldn't you just count them yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the list of all outfits from various sources such as [this one from IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-odyssey/Outfits_and_Costumes).  There are 43 distinct costume sets though 3 of them only have one piece rather than both.  The [skeleton suit](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uAbgIrGngTA/maxresdefault.jpg) and [boxer shorts](https://www.nintendo-insider.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/boxer-shorts-super-mario-odyssey-screenshot.jpeg) only have body pieces while the invisibility cap is only a hat.

This brings the total to **41 hats** and **42 body outfits**.  There are no outfit pieces that you can only unlock via Amiibo, though they can be used to unlock some of the more expensive pieces such as Wedding Peach and Wedding Bowser.

**EDIT:**  It's very difficult to determine the number of currently obtainable outfits as most trustworthy sources only wrote outfit guides when the game was released and didn't update them when DLC was released (most of which included new outfits).

Based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bIhiZMQMwo) which seems to be complete, there were 13 new outfit and hat combinations as well as the 8-bit Mario Cap added as DLC.  This brings the total to **55 hats and 55 outfits**.

Comment: The Hakama suit doesn't have a hat, and the Captain's Hat doesn't have a costume.

Answer (score 3):

As of writing, including DLC, there are **49 hats and 50 outfits.** However, data miners have confirmed several more outfits and hats to come, bringing the total to **54 hats and 54 outfits.**

*As of writing, the missing outfits are Harriet, Spewart, Zombie, and Santa, while the missing hats are the same four, plus 8-bit.*

Answer (score 1):

They keep adding more. I believe there are currently 48 hats and 49 outfits.

Answer (score 0):

But I have right now 51 hats it has a golden star
And 50 outfits which I must be missing one but there are some still left in crazy cap.There are a total of in between 52 and 55 hats and outfits

Answer (score 0):

There are 51 hats, and 52 bodies, because of the only-body and only-hat costumes.

Answer (score -1):

[eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-11-21-super-mario-odyssey-hats-list-prices-how-to-unlock-every-hat-cap-4847)

[eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-11-21-super-mario-odyssey-outfits-list-prices-how-to-unlock-every-costume-outfit-suit-4847)
There are 40 hats, 42 outfits in the Odyssey.